# Different ways to start PowerShell

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, powershell

A .exe file found by some instances of PowerShell and not others got me questioning what is the difference between:

- Starting PowerShell in a folder from the explorer context menu that appears on "shift + right click". (In my case, the file is not found by this shell)
- Starting PowerShell from the context menu that appears when right clicking the lower left corner of the desktop. (In my case, the file is found by this shell)

Details:

- Windows 10 Pro, 64 bit. Version 1709, Build 16299.431
- When starting from the explorer context window:

  - The window title is "Windows PowerShell" and the terminal reads "PS" followed by a space and the path to the current folder.
  - $PSVersionTable.PSVersion returns Major 5 , Minor 1 , Build 16299, Revision 431
- When starting it from the desktop, the only difference with starting it from explorer is that "Windows PowerShell" and the copyright information is shown before the terminal line.

Comment: As the person who made the comment, I can tell you, this is not due to running PowerShell in the incorrect user context.  Can you supply us information more specific about your system, providing your own screenshots, will help answer your question.  You should indicate which version of PowerShell you are using, and which version of Windows if you are using Windows 10 include which build you have installed.

Comment: try `.\file.exe` instead of just `file.exe`

Comment: @SimonS it didn't work.

Comment: @Ramhound I've edited in the requested info. Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you run `[System.IO.FileInfo]::new($theFile)` where `$theFile` is the full path to your file? What is the output of `[System.Environment]::Is64BitProcess`?

Comment: It was not a duplicate, but I wasn't sure at the time of writing. I reformulated the question to be more useful and removed the link.

Comment: @ben N thanks, I haven't been able to try this yet.

Comment: @fixer1234 can you please remove the "possible duplicate" tag ? It was not a duplicate, and it was clearly explained in the original question.

Comment: Also try `where powershell` in a classic command prompt.

Answer (score -1):

There are various ways by which you can open powershell in windows 10.
Some of the ways are:

By pressing `win+x i` for opening in normal mode and `win+x a` for opening in Anmin Mode.

You can also use the following command in the Command prompt(cmd) or RunAs Dialog Box for getting the PowerShell Window with desired Title in the traditional CMD styled window.

```
cmd /k PowerShell -NoExit -Command "& {$host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = 'Powershell'}"
```

P.S: Its like traditional CMD with PowerShell features and Syntax Highlighting.

Comment: `win+x i` doesn't do anything for me on Windows 10. `win+x a` opens a normal `cmd.exe`, not `powershell`.